# dynamically pass built-in session variables to workflow variables

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I want to maintain audit information of each and every mapping in table which contains

```
workflow_name | start_time | end_time | source_success_rows | target_success_rows | error_record_count
```

i am able to do it using `workflow variables` assigning them with built-in `session variables` 
and then using the property of prevariableAssignment in session assigning the  workflowflow variables to mapping variables of audit_session

It is working fine , But the issue is if i want to maintain audit for other mapping i have to create the whole process again .
So is there any possibility of automating the process so that it does not require recreation of the whole thing again.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to build a process reading from the informatica repository, wherein the exact same information is available, although spread across different tables.

you'd be able to make a single mapping/quer, extract that piece of information, and feed to your table...